# Have to add three attributes to change two inputs CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to change the design of two input fields where the input type is "email" and "password". Here is my CSS code.

```
form input [type = "email"], [type = "password"], [type = "email"] {
color: black;
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

This snippet of code will change the design for the input fields with the type "email" and "password".

```
form input [type = "email"], [type = "password"] {
color: black;
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

However, this snippet of code will only change the input field design with the type "password". Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: spaces have meaning in CSS selector

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 input[type = "email"], input[type = "password"] {
      color: black;
      border-bottom: 2px solid red;
 }
```